# Elliptic Curve - distinguish between two points after multiplication

Tags: elliptic-curves

If $P$ and $Q$ are two points on an elliptic curve of large prime order, given $P, Q$, and a point $R$ which is either (a) $nP$ or (b) $nQ$, is it possible to determine if $R$ is of form (a) or form (b)? Here $n$ is a secret.

Answer (score 8):

As there exist both $n_1$ and $n_2$ such that $R=n_1P$ and $R=n_2Q$, $R$ is of form both a) and b). In general all elements of a cyclic group of prime order are generators and so all elements are multiples of all other elements (if the group operation is written additively).

Comment: I don't claim that my answer is covering the distinguishing, however, I don't see how this does?

Comment: It shows that distinguishing is impossible because both derivations are equally possible.

Comment: Actually, the point coordinates are not random, which is not close to claiming with a simple argument.

Comment: At no point do I claim that the point coordinates are random.